# How to use Angular js as view/template engine in Nodejs/Express

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I've tried using EJS template engine but want to know is there any way to use angular js as an template engine for nodejs

Comment: I believe it is not possible. When you use angular you get more than just templating. Those extra features rely on DOM APIs which aren't available on the server. Id recommend looking into other purely templating solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try fullstack javascript framework `http://mean.io/`

link to tutorial https://youtu.be/bIj_Skg7eWw